# Making a .htaccess Rewrite Rule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I have just redesigned an e-commerce website and I need to redirect old product pages to new ones, using .htaccess file.

What should be the Rewrite Rule to redirect all pages, like this example :

```
www.mydomain.com/shop/catalogue,4697,product_name.htm
```

to

```
www.mydomain.com/fr/4697-.html
```

As you can see, it's based on the product ID ( 4697 in my example ).

Thanks for your help !

Comment: You may be better looking at 301 redirects than just vanilla `RewriteRule`s.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/shop/.+\,(\d+)\,.+\.htm$
RewriteRule ^ /fr/%1-.html [L,R=301]
```

Comment: @Emmanuel Do you have `whatevernumber-.html` as a file? If not what is your actual URL?